# Else block not executing

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a php script, with if and else blocks. Both contain echo statements only. The if block executes perfectly but when the else block executes nothing at all is printed to screen (not even the echo statements OUTSIDE the blocks). I have tried many things such as capitalising the ELSE statement, checking all the braces are there, double and triple checking the syntax to no avail. Please help.

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('config.inc');

$usr = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['****ID']);

// Retrieve email address and message from database according to user's input
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$usr'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Put the id numbers in array $row

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

// Test for ID match

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
echo 'The email address of ';
echo $usr;
echo ' is: ';
echo $row['email'];
echo '<p>Message: ';
echo $row['firstname'];
}
else
{
echo 'Sorry it appears that ';
echo '$usr';
echo ' has not registered yet. Why dont you tell him about ****Jacker?'; 
}
// Executing outside  if..else blocks for testing
echo 'Sorry, it appears that ';
echo '$usr';
echo ' has not registered yet. Why dont you tell him about ****Jacker?'; 

?>
```

Comment: Add `var_dump(mysql_num_rows($result));` right in front of the `if()` and see what the value is. Maybe the result of `mysql_num_rows($result)` is not what you think it is?

Comment: Sounds like a parser error. Can you run the same script with `error_reporting(-1)` prepended to its PHP part?

Comment: indeed, and else you can do `if(false)` to make sure it goes to the else statement, and see what it does...

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: whenever condition becomes false else part is not outputting???

Comment: You kill the script if there is no result. Dint expect to run to run the else block and the rest now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have an error in

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

Since the number of results is zero, your script will print a warning. Depending on your configuration, it's possible you see a white-page in stead of the warning.

Please note the
    or die(..)
part.

Since the first part failed (fetching an empty result), the script will die and stop. No code lower than this line will be executed, so no logs, no if, ...

Best solution is to put the fetch_array inside the if (mysql_num_rows(..) == 1 statement, so we are sure there is at least 1 user to fetch

Comment: You cannot fetch a empty result? Put this line inside the if, when you have for sure at least one result

Comment: Please note you have 'or die(..) , the first part (fetching empty result) failed, so you ask the script to die.. logical he don't continue with the code, nor print any other code you define later on

Comment: Mr De Laender you are a star mate - problem solved, thanks very much!

Comment: To fix the problem remove $row = my... Line and replace if statement's condition with $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)